# At both 25% (each)-to include or not?

Tags: sentence-construction

[image]

On the picture shown, should I say it this way:

> Coal and natural gas were the highest units of electricity, which were **both 25%.**

Or

> Coal and natural gas were the highest units of electricity, which were **both 25% each**.

Comment: The numbers on those pie charts are units, not percentages. If they were percentages, the total would add up to 100, and 25 would take up an exact quarter of a circle. 25/90 = 27.8%, not 25%.

Comment: If you're using both, you don't need to use each as well. Use one or the other. "Most units of electricity were fuelled by coal and natural gas, each providing 25 units" or "Both coal and natural gas fuel sources provided 25 units of electricity, the joint highest source."

Answer (score 3):

You can use either "each" or "both", but not both: "which were 25% each" or "which were both 25%".

Also, "which were" is a little verbose, so instead I might say "at 25% each" or "both at 25%".

But as J.R. says, they're not actually percentages, they're mystery units: "25 units each".

*Units of electricity* means something like *watts* or *kilowatt-hours* or *gigajoules*, or the unexplained units used in these charts. Coal and natural gas are *sources* of electricity.

*Highest* doesn't work for comparing things that aren't, so you want *largest* instead. (Or "main": "the main sources of electricity" has a slightly different meaning but it's still appropriate.)

So I'd write it like this: "Coal and natural gas were the main sources of electricity, at 25 units each." (But I'd want to find out what those "units" are and replace them with the actual unit.)

(Wow, I didn't know France's heavy use of nuclear power was that recent.)

Comment: It doesn't matter what the units are. If they total 100, then they can also be considered as the equivalent in percentage terms. 25 out of 100 is still 25% of the total.

Comment: @JasonB - Yes, but in the OP's picture, they total 90, not 100.

Comment: @J.R. Right, so in *this* case, it would be 28%. The point is that you don't *have* to use units. There's nothing at all wrong with using percentages. (If the math is correct.)